# Appending to div puts first item at bottom, and rest in correct order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add items into a div by appending to the end of the div during a for loop. The idea being I have records from a database with a "Total score" field, and I want the highest-scoring records on top.

The container div where I want to put the elements is this:

`<div id="fetch-n-sites-output"></div>`

And my callback function upon a successful AJAX call is as follows:

```
function updateNSites(data){
    $("#fetch-n-sites-output").empty();
    data["fetched-sites"].map(function(element, index){
        var cloned = cloneTemplate(index, element);
        console.log(`Processing site ${index}...`);
        $("#fetch-n-sites-output").append(cloned);
    });

}
```

For completeness, my `cloneTemplate` function is this:

```
function cloneTemplate(index, data){
    // CLONE TEMPLATE
    var template = $("#test-template").html().trim();
    var clone = $(template);

    var siteID = data["site_id"];
    var totalSiteScore = data["total_site_score"];

    // UPDATE CLONE WITH SITE-SPECIFIC INFORMATION
    // 0. Update ID of div element with site id
    var mainDiv = $("div.greendiv").eq(index);
    mainDiv.attr("id", `site-${siteID}`);

    // 1. Update header with "Site ID: {site_id}"
    $(`#site-${siteID} > div.reddiv > p.header-text`).text(`Site ID: ${siteID} - Total Score: ${totalSiteScore}`);

    // 2. Add event handlers
    // $(`#site-${siteID} div.site-sidenav`).on("click", 'a', function() {
    //     alert("clicky");
    // });
    $(`#site-${siteID}`).find(".site-navlink").on("click", function () {
        alert("clicky");
    });
    // SHOW CLONE
    clone.removeClass("template-hidden").addClass("template-show");
    return clone;
}
```

When I retrieve 3 sites, the highest scoring site is always at the bottom. This doesn't make sense to me, because my SQL query orders by this total site score. The highest scoring site is always placed at the bottom, but the other sites are ordered properly:

[image]

Another odd problem (which I think is related to this main issue) is that the event handlers that I add in the `cloneTemplate` function to handle clicks on the `<a>` tags (right now just calls an `alert()` for testing) only work on the elements other than the first:

Whereas clicking 'GENERAL' on the first element does not trigger an alert. Could someone please help me figure out why every added element but the first behaves properly, but the first does not? And why the first element is always getting placed at the bottom? Thank you

Comment: I'd probably try to fix this a couple ways: first, you should probably fix the question. It's suspicious that it's not behaving how you want. Second, regardless of fixing the query, you could just sort the data correctly on the front-end first and then append in the correct order.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "it's suspicious that it's not behaving how you want" please? I agree, based on what I understand about the append function, but that doesn't give me much insight into why it is not behaving properly. In the meantime I'll give the sorting on the front end a shot

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood your issue. My assumption is that the data was coming from the API in the wrong order. Have you confirmed that the SQL query is returning data in the right order?

Comment: Yes, when I do a raw data-dump to the console, the site scores are in the correct order

Comment: ah okay, then _both_ of my proposed solutions might not work. Let me look at your code closer and sorry for the incorrect recommendation

Comment: No worries, the help is appreciated regardless

Comment: For your click handler, I would just remove it from the clone function and put it outside of the functions and change it to delegate as:  **$(document).on("click",".site-navlink",function(** This will allow it to always work and you can still determine what was clicked by referring to **$(this)** in the function

Comment: This might not be useful at all, but instead of **map** have you tried **$.each(data["fetched-sites"],function**? or a **forEach** loop? Map is really meant for filtering through and creating a new array. **Since map builds a new array, using it when you aren't using the returned array is an anti-pattern; use forEach or for...of instead.** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Switched and tried both the forEach and the $.each. They successfully created the elements on the page, but did not solve the issue regarding the highest-ranking site being placed on the bottom